# How does Linux know how much physical memory is used by a process?

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory

I was investigating memory usage of an example process. First I allocate some memory, check what is the size of virtual memory and resident memory (in RAM). Then I write data to the allocated memory and check again these values.

```
int main()
{
 int pid = getpid();
 std::stringstream s;
 s << "cat /proc/" << pid << "/status | grep \"VmSize\\|VmRSS\"";
 std::string command = s.str();
 std::cout << "Before allocation\n";
 system(command.c_str());
 char* mem = new char[10000000];
 std::cout << "After allocation\n";
 system(command.c_str());
 memset(mem, 0, 10000000);
 std::cout << "After writing\n";
 system(command.c_str());
 return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
Before allocation
VmSize:     3412 kB
VmRSS:       852 kB
After allocation
VmSize:    13180 kB
VmRSS:       852 kB
After writing
VmSize:    13180 kB
VmRSS:     10568 kB
```

When memory is allocated by operator new, only the value of VmSize changes. When data is written to the memory, then value of VmRSS changes. How does Linux know how much physical memory (VmRSS) is used by a process?

Comment: The operating system knows because it is what handles allocating and managing memory for each process. What exactly are you asking here? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: How does operating system know that when data is written to some memory address, then it is reflected in VmRSS value. For example, when memory is allocated, the process can call mmap system call to get some memory from OS, so OS can track it. But when data is just written to this memory, then no system calls are called. When something like that is done *ptr = data, then no system calls are called, but somehow OS knows that this data is now physically in RAM and it's reflected in VmRSS value.

Comment: I can't say exactly how Linux works (although I'm sure Google could), but in Windows, there is a distinction between *reserved* memory and *committed* memory. You reserve a block of memory using `malloc` (or `mmap` or whatever), but it may not actually be committed yet. When you access that block of memory, if it has not yet been committed, this generates a page fault exception, which the system handles, committing the memory (*i.e.*, mapping the memory to either physical memory or the page file). So you don't need to explicitly make a system call because the system handles the PF exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How does Linux know how much physical memory (VmRSS) is used by a process?

When the process tries to access virtual memory that has not been mapped to physical memory, the CPU (assuming it has a hardware memory management unit) will trigger an interrupt (specifically, a page fault) that is handled by the operating system. The operating system allocates the physical memory to the process and updates the translation look aside buffer (part of the MMU, which is used to map virtual memory to physical).

So, since it is the operating system that allocates the physical memory, it can also track how much it has allocated to each process.